# How do I debug vim indentexpr script?

Tags: debugging, vim

I have downloaded a verilog/systemverilog indent file which looks really comprehensive. However, there is a problem: it doesn't work. I'm looking at the vimscript code and want to both fix it (I'm on vim 8.2, maybe there's a version mismatch) as well as enhance it. However, I'm running into issues debugging. Specifically, indentexpr scripts have a variable v:lnum which is set when indentkey is pressed and the indentexpr is evaluated.

BUT, I don't know of a way to enter debug mode on just the indentexpr call. I tried manually calling the function inside the vimscript but that leaves v:lnum as some garbage number (well, the last line to invoke indentexpr). Is there a way to enter debug mode when I actually hit a key that invokes indentexpr?

Answer (score 2):

The best way for `v:lnum` to be used is as an argument to the function. Here's an example: vim-ruby's indentexpr setting used to look like this:

```
setlocal indentexpr=GetRubyIndent()
```

Inside the function, the variable `v:lnum` was used to get the line number that it was called on. This, as you've discovered, is pretty inconvenient. So, the better way is:

```
setlocal indentexpr=GetRubyIndent(v:lnum)
```

So, find the place in the script where the `indentexpr` is set and change it to take the magic `v:lnum` variable as an argument. You could then rewrite the function itself to take a single argument:

```
function! GetRubyIndent(lnum)
```

Now, in that function, the `a:lnum` variable will be the line number, and you can call the function with that argument. Search-and-replace `v:lnum` with `a:lnum` everywhere in the function. The indent script should now work as it did before, and you'll be able to call the function manually with a line number.

Here's the specific commit that does this in the vim-ruby repository, as [an example](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/commit/bcdd3f93e7c4c1aec02131ea8bf9c5afe07bf767)

Additionally, `echomsg "foo"` will print a message that you can read afterwards by running the `:messages` command. And I can recommend the [Decho](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Decho) plugin for easy-to-read debug messages.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just setting v:lnum when entering debug mode. That also works. But it is pretty inefficient.